# javascript separate vertical scroll bar for div inside dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, scrollbar

I have a jQuery dialog, containing three divs, and I would like the middle one to have a vertical scroll bar when its content exceeds its height.
The first (top) div should stay fixed at the top of the dialog box, and the third (lower) div should stay fixed at the bottom of the dialog box (like headers and footers in a document).

The dialog box should be movable inside the webpage, so css with position absolute or fixed doesn't help.

Not sure if I'm very clear with this, although I do have some javascript knowledge I am not a programmer.

Thanks in advance for any hint,

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

If you give that div `overflow: auto` it will get scrollbars if it needs them. (Or `overflow-y: auto` to just do a vertical one, on modern browsers.) You may also need `height` and/or `max-height` to keep it from just expanding to accommodate its full content.

Comment: Oh that was so simple... of course it works. Thanks very much!

Comment: Oops... to ready to tell. It works indeed under Chrome, but Firefox still makes it difficult. With Firefox, there is still one big vertical scrollbar for all three divs, whereas what I would need is only one scrollbar for the middle div.